# Find a row by rowindex and then specific td in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to access a `row` by `rowindex` and then its second `td`. I've searched a lot to find a row by its index. But didn't find anything helpful.

a for `loop` is already working as you can see in following code, now i just to want get every row by its index and then its specific td's text.

**Below is the already written code which i want to utilize:**

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('ucInvoiceItems_dgInvoice');

for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
                    var lblMarkupAmount = $("#ucInvoiceItems_dgInvoice_lblMarkupAmount_" + i);
                    var txtMarkupAmount = $("#ucInvoiceItems_dgInvoice_txtMarkupAmount_" + i);
                    var txtMarkupValue = $("#txtMarkupValue");
                    var lblMarkup = $("#lblMarkup");

                    lblMarkupAmount.hide();

                    txtMarkupValue.hide();
                    lblMarkup.html("0.00");                 

                    if ( Math.round( txtMarkupAmount.val()) > 0) {
                        txtMarkupAmount.show();
                        ChangePercent(0);
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the structure of your markup, but assuming the ID is `myTable`, you could do this:

```
var text = $('#myTable tbody tr').eq(index).find('td:nth-of-type(2)').text();
```

Comment: is there any way that loop should not work for the header of table?

Comment: Since I'm using `tbody` in the selector, this will only return rows from the body. If you want the headers too, just leave that out of the selector: `$('#myTable tr')`

Answer (score 1):

To get the table row by its index:

```
// Gets first table row
var $tableRow = $('#tableId tbody tr:eq(0)');
```

Getting the td by its index:

```
$('td:eq(3) input', $tableRow).text();
```